# Click event only triggers once, after the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event in jQuery.  The desired behavior is for a function to execute every time the link is clicked.  However, the actual behavior is that the page loads and then the function is executed once and never again.  The offending code follows.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
#sub {
position:fixed;
z-index:999;
margin-top:180px;
margin-left:200px;
display:none;}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function showdiv(divid) {
   $('.menu').hide();
   $('#'+divid).fadeToggle('slow');
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#opt1').click(showdiv('sub'));
    $('a#opt2').click(function(){$('.menu').hide();});
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <li><a id="opt1" href="#">Option1</a></li>
    <li><a id="opt2" href="#">Option2</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="sub">
    <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are supposed to pass the function name to `.click`, not the returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to pass the function reference to `.click`. In your case, you passed the returned value of you function instead of the actual function. Long story short, you should wrap it with `function(){}`:

```
$('a#opt1').click(function(){
    showdiv('sub');
});
```

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on `.click` actually states that you have to pass a function, but instead you passed `undefined` in your example. That is why it only executed once.

Answer (score 1):

`$('a#opt1').click(showdiv('sub'));` will run the function `showdiv` immediately, setting the return value as what is called `onclick` (in this case, nothing, hence your click handler seems to not work).

You should wrap this in an anonymous function.

```
$('a#opt1').click(function() { showdiv('sub') });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the function in an anonymous function:

```
$('a#opt1').click(function() {
    showdiv('sub');
});
```